# $_COOKIE does not return all values on only one page

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

During the login process on my internal webpage I use setcookie() to write a cookie.

```
setcookie("cookiewar",$loginname,time()+(3600*24*100));
```

On all pages (except one) var_dump($_COOKIE) shows me an array count of 2:

> array(2) { ["cookievar"]=> string(37) "klaus" ["PHPSESSID"]=>
>   string(26) "btmep2lk2l8thua18ibdbsa8b3" }

On the one (and only) page I only get:

> array(1) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(26) "btmep2lk2l8thua18ibdbsa8b3" }

Does anyone have an idea why this could happen on this page?

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the problem and the solution by myself.
The one page was the only one located in a different folder than all others.
The cookie was only valid in the folder the cookie was created.
With

```
setcookie("cookiewar",$loginname,time()+(3600*24*100),"/");
```

I set the cookie the top level folder and this solved it.